# Sorting a 2 dimensional array on multiple columns

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

I need to sort a 2 dimensional array of doubles on multiple columns using either C or C++. Could someone point me to the algorithm that I should use or an existing library (perhaps boost?) that has this functionality?

I have a feeling that writing a recursive function may be the way to go but I am too lazy to write out the algorithm or implement it myself if it has been done elsewhere. :-)

Thanks

Comment: You can only sort on one column at a time.  However, if two elements of the sorted column are equal, you CAN fall back to another secondary column...  By the way, the words `"I am too lazy"` never come across well.

Comment: Well I have done a fair bit of coding where I know that there is NO existing code (e.g., MCMC samplers for various statistical models which extend the state of the art.). I prefer to be lazy instead of  re-inventing a wheel especially in an area I am confident that there should be something out there.

Comment: 1) What order? Sort each collumn separately? Sort along rows? Along Collumns? 2) Is the minor size fixed or is it array of pointers?

Comment: good programmers are lazy programmers :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (C++) or [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (C or C++) to perform the sorting operation. The tricky part is that you need to define a custom comparison function for comparing your rows. For example:

```
 bool compareTwoRows(double* rowA, double* rowB){
     return ( (rowA[0]<rowB[0]) || ((rowA[0]==rowB[0])&&(rowA[1]<rowB[1])) );
 }

 // ...
 double** two_dimensional_array = // ...
 int rows = // ... number of rows ... 
 std::sort(two_dimensional_array,two_dimensional_array+rows,&compareTwoRows);
 // ...
```

Comment: That should work. I knew about qsort and std::sort but never thought to extend the compare function to more than 1 column.

I will implement it and will accept your answer if it works for me. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: You could also use std::stable_sort - just sort the array repeatedly, starting with the _least_ significant column.

Comment: this one is the perfect answer..!! thanks @michael aaron safyan

Comment: Nick's solution is good because it generalizes to higher dimensions well! Imagine writing that comparison operator for more than two columns, it would get complicated fast

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
// Order function. Change the 2 for the column number you want to use
bool compareRowsByColumn(vector<double> rowA, vector<double> rowB){
  return (rowA[2] < rowB[2]);
}

// The sorting line. Matrix is the two dimensional vector.
sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), &compareRowsByColumn);
```