# C++ 2D Array Sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, 2d

I am trying to sort the elements in 2d array like this:

> 338 640
>   723.771
>   62.1603
>
> 364 804
>   882.56
>   65.642
>
> 199 664
>   693.179
>   73.3166

I need to sort them regards to 3rd and 4th columns.

*For instance for the 3rd column:*

> 199 664 **693.179** 73.3166
>
> 338 640 **723.771** 62.1603
>
> 364 804 **882.56** 65.642

*For the 4th column:*

> 338 640 723.771 **62.1603**
>
> 364 804 882.56 **65.642**
>
> 199 664 693.179 **73.3166**

I hope I could explain what I want to do. Thanks for help already..

---

**Answer:**

I've found what need it. I am putting the codes here maybe it could be helpful for someone else.

this is compare function for columns:

```
bool Compare(vector<double> A, vector<double> B) {
    return (A[2] < B[2]); // 2 means which column that you want to compare

}
```

and this is the sorting code:

```
std::sort(dots.begin(), dots.end(), &Compare); // "dots" needs to be a vector. in this case its a 2d double vector
```

*the source is : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37516971/5331586*

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304553/how-to-sort-a-2d-array-according-to-the-second-column-using-stl-sort-function

Comment: It seems a multivariable objective function. How do you handle the following case: r1 and r2 are the two row of a matrix; r1[2] < r2[2] but r2[3] < r2[3]? (Indices starts from 0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use std::sort with your own comparator. I would solve it like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class Comparate2DArrayByColumn {
public:
    Comparate2DArrayByColumn(int column)
        : column(column)
    {
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const std::vector<T>& array1, const std::vector<T>& array2)
    {
        // do not use [] here, it will be UB
        return array1.at(column) > array2.at(column);
    }

private:
    int column;
};

void printArray(const std::vector<std::vector<double> >& array)
{
    for (auto& line : array) {
        for (auto val : line) {
            cout << val << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > array = {
        { 33, 640, 723.771, 62.1603 },
        { 364, 804, 882.56, 65.642 },
        { 199, 664, 693.179, 73.3166 },
    };

    printArray(array);
    cout << endl
         << endl;

    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(), Comparate2DArrayByColumn(2));

    printArray(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it wasn't really useful and should have been a comment until you added an example.

Comment: Also `Comparate2DArrayByCollumn` should not be templated and instead `operator()` should be templated.  That way you don't need to do `Comparate2DArrayByCollumn<double>(2)` but can instead use `Comparate2DArrayByCollumn(2)`

Comment: That takes into account just the third column, what about the fourth?

Comment: @biagio-festa use std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(), Comparate2DArrayByCollumn<double>(3);

Comment: @devalone then the sorting respect to (2) will be lost :D

Comment: thanks for the code @devalone. I've tried to add codes my project but I had some errors in <algorithm> :/. I think it's about type of array and I am not very familiar with classes.